# TS2322 TS2345 but ___ could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint

Tags: typescript

How to deal with this annoying new class of error? I did not even initialize T. I tried TypeScript 4.0.8 and 4.3.5.

```
// error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'.
//   'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number'.
function abc<T extends string | number>(): T {
    return 1;
}

// error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
//   'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number'.
function abc<T extends string | number>(cb: (t: T) => void) {
    cb(1);
}
```

Ideally type narrowing should be available on T through logic.

```
if (...) {
   T is number
} else {
   T is string
}
```

More ridiculousness. (fully matched the type but still fails.)

```
// error TS2322: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'T'.
//   'string | number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number'.
//     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
//       'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number'.
function abc<T extends string | number>(): T {
    return 1 as (string | number);
}
```

I am currently getting around this problem by returning/callback `as any`. The narrowing is done in logic so **passing in a parameter of type T while it works will not help here**.

Comment: The error is saying that `T` might be something more specific than `number` (or more specific than `string`). Like for example, `T` could be the type `4 | 5`. If that's the case, then returning 1 will not match the type `4 | 5`. I'm not sure what to recommend, because i don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you give some more details about what you want this code to achieve?

Comment: The error messages here are pretty reasonable. `T extends string | number` indicates that `T` can be a subtype of `string | number`. So the return type being `string | number` is not sufficient if `T` is `string`.

Comment: I am not looking for subtypes, only discriminating the union. You are both correct this will still fail without the union. With this in mind casting `as T` works! ```function abc<T extends number>(): T { return 1 as T; }``` __Question Answered__

Comment: `I am not looking for subtypes, only discriminating the union` But you've set it up to use generics. That brings along with it the possibility of subtypes. `With this in mind casting as T works! ` Asserting to typescript that 1 is a `T` may make the compilation errors go away, but it can cause problems at runtime. Why is this code using generics in the first place?

Comment: True, generics are not appropriate. __function overloading__ with value for parameter is what I needed in my situation (with an extra overload to handle variable input (both) case).